# Hot to extract data from bunch of html markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to identify the texts from `CKeditor`.

The `ckData` contains html markup and tables from Ckeditor that is input from users.

For example

```
text here texts here texts here
second line texts...etc.
<br>
<table>
  ...
</table>

more texts here...

<table>
....
</table>
```

I want be able to get all texts from the ckData.

I can get table texts with the following codes

```
   var contents = {};
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    var instance = this;
    temp.innerHTML = ckData;

    var tables = temp.getElementsByTagName('table')
    //use tables as array...
    for(var i = 0; i<tables.length; i++){
        var table = tables[i];
        contents.rowsCount = $('tr', table).length;
        contents.columnsCount = $('td', table).length / question.rowsCount;
        contents.texts='';

        $(table).find('td').each(function(){
                contents.push($(this).text().trim());
                contents.texts += $(this).text()
        })
    }
```

I want to be able to extract texts outside of table WHILE maintain the original order of the ckData.

so the final `contents` variable I was hoping to get is like:

```
first part of texts

table cell data //got this

second part of texts

table cell data //got this
```

I got the `table cell` data but I am not sure how to get the `texts` outside of `table` structure.

I hope I explain it well. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Why not just use `temp.textContent` (note that you will lose formatting)?

Comment: @PaulS. thanks, but I need to maintain the html markup for texts outside of table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get text inside of container that is not part of children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819953/how-to-get-text-inside-of-container-that-is-not-part-of-children)...which is ironically, a possible duplicate of [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)...duplicateception

Comment: Then as you're already using a `temp` parent; convert the table text to a TextNode `var text = document.createTextNode(tableText)`, at the end inside each loop do `tables[i].parentNode.insertBefore(text, tables[i]);` then remove the table `tables[i].parentNode.removeChild(tables[i])`, so you effectively replace your `<table>` elements with their text, then you can keep all html markup by converting the contents of `temp` to string in your favourite way.

Comment: you can just remove the tables and grab the .innerText from the common container.

Comment: @PaulS. and Dandavis thanks guys, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use `.text()` function in jQuery. It returns just the text and trims all the markup code.